# Confused about iconv conversion from iso-8859-1 to utf-8

Tags: bash, iconv

I was trying to convert txt files from iso-8859-1 to utf-8, when I noticed that some of the strings, which contained swedish characters, were not properly decoded. The weird part was when I converted back to iso-8859-1, the file was still utf-8, but also the string was properly decoded this time... does anyone know why this happens?

String in iso-8859-1:

> ≈kersberga

Converting the file to utf-8:

```
for file in ~/blabla/*
do
    echo "${file}"
    iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t UTF-8 "${file}" > "${file}.tmp"
    rm "${file}"
    mv "${file}.tmp" "${file}"
done
```

String in utf-8:

> Ã…kersberga

Doing it again, but reversed:

```
for file in ~/blabla/*
do
    echo "${file}"
    iconv -f UTF-8 -t iso-8859-1"${file}" > "${file}.tmp"
    rm "${file}"
    mv "${file}.tmp" "${file}"
done
```

Checking with `file -b --mime-encoding` -> the file is still utf-8

But the string is also decoded properly this time:

> Åkersberga

Comment: Running `file -b --mime-encoding` results in utf-8

Comment: The `≈` character _does not exist_ in ISO-8859-1, so having a string in ISO-8859-1 that contains this character is simply impossible. Try it yourself (if your shell and terminal are using UTF-8): `echo "≈" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t iso-8859-1` gives `iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0`.

Comment: Remember that `file` is *guessing* at the encoding type from the contents. Sometimes it guesses wrong. Sadly, it's not at all unusual for it to be **impossible** to tell what encoding a file is in.

Comment: Hm, I double checked it, using `file -b --mime-encoding bla.txt` it resulted in `iso-8859-1`, checked the file, the string indeed has the `≈ ` character...

Comment: @14mble - Then at some point, you're accidentally converting it in the process of checking it.

Comment: "Checked the file" how? Which encoding did you use when opening/viewing the file?

Comment: That is true @T.J.Crowder...

Comment: @Thomas I opened the file just with a regular text editor.

Comment: Can you try first do dos2unix file.txt and then iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t UTF-8 file.txt  ? it looks like becasue of unix format first operation is fails, but redirection works in unix format.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was with iconv, upgrading libiconv to 1.17 solved the issue.